# How to recreate menu like the right nav menu at getbootstrap.com

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On the website for bootstrap, they have a nav menu on the right side that stays in place as you scroll down, and it will also follow you as your scroll through the sections.  How does this work?  I have attempted to look through the page's source, and can't find what it's called anywhere or how to do it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this recently. Check it out here [easy way navbar bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458567/easy-way-navbar-bootstrap/23458641#23458641)

Or I pasted it below.

If you're looking to add the fixed sidebar like bootstrap uses for their docs, like noted here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix, try this:

Add `id="foo" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" data-offset-bottom="10"` to the  or  you want to lock in place upon scroll.

and add the javascript at the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#foo').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
    , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
</script>
From there, you'll want to adjust the height at which you want it to lock by adjusting the 'top' elements.

For example:

<div id="foo" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" data-offset-bottom="10">
  <!-- everything in here is be fixed to top -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#foo').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
        , bottom: function () {
           return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two tools that are good to use that are built into your browser if you are using firefox or chrome.
I am using chrome so will explain how i found the following info in chrome.
1) load the page in chrome and right click. select "inspect element". it helps if you right-click on the item you want to inspect.
2) when the developer tools opens on the bottom you will see the html mark up on the left. hovering over it will highlight the corresponding elements on the page.
3) the right hand side shows you the css and even lets you turn off or on certain aspects of the css, add new rules, change rules etc... 
so when i do this i see that the side nav bar is a `<ul>` with the `class=nav bs-docs-sidenav` and it is in a `div` with `class=bs-docs-sidebar`.

once you have a bit of html or a class to search for you can right click anywhere on the screen and click view page source. search (ctrl-f) for that class or something that is most likely used in the spot you are looking for and see if you can find the html. that is how i grabbed the following code snippet from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="bs-docs-sidebar hidden-print" role="complementary">
            <ul class="nav bs-docs-sidenav">

                <li>
  <a href="#download">Download</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#whats-included">What's included</a>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#whats-included-precompiled">Precompiled</a></li>
    <li><a href="#whats-included-source">Source code</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>.....
```

Answer (score 0):

That menu is called an affix and you can use bootstrap itself to do it - here's the doc for it: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 0):

I was *also* trying to replicate the side navigation from http://getbootstrap.com but couldn't find an easy solution, so I created a plugin for it:

http://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/

Let me know what you think!