# easy way navbar bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I started to use Bootstrap. Right now I am looking for a navbar in bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). The side navbar html and JavaScript I tried to take (the fixed side navbar see it in the link not the example in the link)

the code:

```
 <ul><li>first menu</li>
 <ul><li>sub menu<li>
 <li>sub menu 2</li>
 <ul>
 <ul>
```

But it's not clear in JavaScript. How to open and select active element when he scroll
and design?

I am looking some open source or project like jqueryui.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/    and    
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Here's a working template: http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/affix-sidebar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recreate menu like the right nav menu at getbootstrap.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303035/how-to-recreate-menu-like-the-right-nav-menu-at-getbootstrap-com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to add the fixed sidebar like bootstrap uses for their docs, like noted here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix, try this:

Add `id="foo" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" data-offset-bottom="10"` to the `<div>` or `<ul>` you want to lock in place upon scroll.

and add the javascript at the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#foo').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
    , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

From there, you'll want to adjust the height at which you want it to lock by adjusting the 'top' elements.

For example:

```
<div id="foo" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" data-offset-bottom="10">
  <!-- everything in here is be fixed to top -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#foo').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
        , bottom: function () {
           return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

FYI, I would suggest a more new title for your post, perhaps "Fixed/sticky navigation with bootstrap." instead of "easy way navbar bootstrap" (just my opinion)

Comment: the fixed side you see it in the link

Comment: thanks for anwser
Q: is affix do everything(decode html and create navbar) 
and do i need affix.js?

Comment: No, you'll need to put navbar inside div#foo